# How can I print out words from a list that contains a particular letter? I know what to do with words starting with specific letter but not in BETWEEN

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is the example list

```
greekAlpha = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "epsilon"]
```

Comment: You mean how do you tell if a character is `in` a string?

Comment: i need to print out words that contains specific letter in between the words. not starting with. example letter: e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is One liner approach to condition

```
a = [print(word) for word in greekAlpha if "a" in word]
```

Comment: He says he wants them printed out...

Comment: @LarrytheLlama yes just edited

Comment: [Is it pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) - `for w in greekAlpha: if "a" in w: print(w)` would be better

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in greekAlpha:
    if word.count(letter) > 0:
        print(word)
```

Comment: i need to print out words that contains specific letter in between the words. not starting with. example letter: e

Comment: Yeah, I put count first then changed it then changed it back.

Comment: @SpicyMeatballs This works (it worked to start off with, but I changed it, then changed it back again so it should work now). Also, this one is handy because you can see how many times it is in there, too.

Comment: THANK YOU LARRY!

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```py
for word in greekAlpha:
    if 'a' in word:
        print(word)
```

If you're worried about case

```py
for word in greekAlpha:
    if letter.lower() in word.lower():
        print(word)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! THIS WORKS!